# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac 1 {\lfloor 1-\log_2(x) \rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\lfloor 1-\log_2(x) \rfloor}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the Greatest Integer Function (GIF)

I learnt that the solution is probably $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac 1 {r \cdot 2^r}.$

But how does that happen?

Comment: Hey on searching the internet for some time now, as expected this question is very similar to a question in the MIT integration bee 2014. That's why on first looking at this question,  it seemed that I have already solved it sometime before.

Comment: @Manthanein Hmm, just had a look. 2014 P18.

Comment: Yep correct about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\frac {1}{\lfloor 1-\log_2 x\rfloor}$$

For $x\in \left(1/2,1\right)$, $f(x)=1$

For $x\in \left(1/4,1/2\right)$, $f(x)=1/2$

For $x\in \left(1/8,1/4\right)$, $f(x)=1/3$

So the integral turns out to be $$\frac 11\cdot\frac 12+\frac 12\cdot\frac 14+\frac 13\cdot\frac 18\cdots= \frac {1}{1\cdot 2^1}+\frac {1}{2\cdot 2^2}+\frac {1}{3\cdot 2^3}\cdots
=    \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{r\cdot 2^r}$$

On further computation you might notice that the answer is simply $\ln 2$

Comment: I don't think this is much of a 'hint'.

Comment: Is that a hint? Yes, I did take a few examples that way but how does that show $1/r \cdot 2^r$

Comment: @Mathbg see,  first try to plot the function graphically according to intervals I stated in the answer. On plotting you see that the integral is just the area under the graph of f(x) which are just rectangles

Comment: @Manthanein Yes, true. But my question is : isn't there a non graphical way?

Comment: @Mathbg I thought graphical way would be the most natural way for thinking over this problem

Comment: @Mathbg prove that it satisfies the hypotheses of a Riemann sum converging to the integral